# Hide some shipping methods if cart has more than 4 items from specific shipping class

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method, product-quantity

Here's the scenario:

I ship trays of drinks using UPS. However, it becomes very difficult to pack 5 trays of drinks into boxes. So I would like to disable UPS shipping method and only display Flat Rate Shipping if a customer orders 5 or more trays of drinks. I have about 7 different drinks, but I can add these drinks to a shipping class to simplify the code.

I want to expand this code to include the quantity of products in a specific the class or perhaps the number of times a product in the shipping class appears. So if the cart has 5 or more of a product in this specific shipping class, it should remove the shipping methods I've specified under array.

How do I expand this code to also include quantity of products?

// If we find the shipping class & quantity of product in the shipping class is equal to or greater than 5.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class( $rates, $package )
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Shipping Class To Find
    $class = 182;

    // Number Of Shipping Class Items In Cart
    $amount = 5;

    // Shipping Methods To Hide
    $method_key_ids = array('wf_shipping_ups:07', 'wf_shipping_ups:08', 'wf_shipping_ups:11', 'wf_shipping_ups:54', 'wf_shipping_ups:65', 'wf_shipping_ups:70', 'wf_shipping_ups:74', 'free_shipping:2', 'request_shipping_quote');

    // Checking In Cart Items
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ) {
        // If We Find The Shipping Class and Number of Items
        if( $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $class && count($package['contents']) >= $amount ){
            foreach( $method_key_ids as $method_key_id ){
                unset($rates[$method_key_id]); // Remove Targeted Methods
            }
            break; // Stop The Loop
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

---

#### Edit - Addition:

Since I purchased the "WooCommerce UPS Shipping Plugin with Print Label" from PluginHive, I have access to their "Manage Shipping Methods" plugin which allows me to do the following:

Set multiple rules to exclude various shipping methods from various shipping classes.
Break the sequence on first occurrence.

The rules I have set-up are as follows:

1. For Class 150 (Break on First Occurrence) - Unset:

wf_shipping_ups:07,
wf_shipping_ups:08,
wf_shipping_ups:11,
wf_shipping_ups:54,
wf_shipping_ups:65,
wf_shipping_ups:70,
wf_shipping_ups:74,
free_shipping:2,
request_shipping_quote.

2. For Class 151 - Unset:
   flat_rate:20,
   flat_rate:21.

I've created a third class 182 in the above code for the products I want to target. It should be treated as class 151 only if less than 5 items of the class are added to the cart.

But it should be treated as Class 150 if 5 or more items are added to the cart.

That's my dilemma.

#### Potential Solution - Addition:

I figured out how to solve my problem. The code @LoicTheAztec assisted me with lets me unset shipping methods for a given shipping class if the product quantity in the cart is 5 or more.

What I need to do now is unset two other shipping methods (flat_rate:20 and flat_rate:21) which is causing the conflict, for the same shipping class (182) but this time for a product quantity in the cart of 4 or less (=<).

Then I can use the existing plugin to create the following rules:

Break on First Occurrence (Check)

1. For Class 150 - Unset:

wf_shipping_ups:07,
wf_shipping_ups:08,
wf_shipping_ups:11,
wf_shipping_ups:54,
wf_shipping_ups:65,
wf_shipping_ups:70,
wf_shipping_ups:74,
free_shipping:2,
request_shipping_quote.

2. For Class 182 - Unset:

Nothing - Because Both Codes Will Create The Logic

3. For Class 151 - Unset:

flat_rate:20,
flat_rate:21.

This should resolve the conflict caused by the plugin.

The million dollar question is...can I somehow use @LoicTheAztec 's solution to set some sort of minimum quantity?

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: Just updated the code. This is what I'm currently running for a different shipping class and it works fine. But I'm not sure how to include quantity for a new shipping class I created.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I've updated the code but haven't tested it on staging yet. Thought I'd let you know.

Comment: @Joundill  I've updated the code but haven't tested it on staging yet. Thought I'd let you know.

Comment: @Joundill AS OP provided related code in his question, you can if you like remove downvote and closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will hide specific defined shipping methods if total items from specific shipping class are 5 or more:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_shipping_class( $rates, $package ) {
    $targeted_class_ids = array(182); // Shipping Class To Find
    $allowed_max_qty    = 4; // Max allowed quantity for the shipping class
    $shipping_rates_ids = array( // Shipping Method rates Ids To Hide
        'wf_shipping_ups:07',
        'wf_shipping_ups:08',
        'wf_shipping_ups:11',
        'wf_shipping_ups:54',
        'wf_shipping_ups:65',
        'wf_shipping_ups:70',
        'wf_shipping_ups:74',
        'free_shipping:2',
        'request_shipping_quote'
    );
    
    $related_total_qty  = 0;

    // Checking cart items for current package
    foreach( $package['contents'] as $key => $cart_item ) {
        if( in_array( $cart_item['data']->get_shipping_class_id(), $targeted_class_ids ) ){
            $related_total_qty += $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
    }
    
    // When total allowed quantity is more than allowed (for items from defined shipping classes)
    if ( $related_total_qty > $allowed_max_qty ) {
        // Hide related defined shipping methods
        foreach( $shipping_rates_ids as $shipping_rate_id ) {
            if( isset($rates[$shipping_rate_id]) ) {
                unset($rates[$shipping_rate_id]); // Remove Targeted Methods
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Untested it should works.

> **Refresh the shipping caches:**
>
> 1. This code is already saved on your functions.php file.
> 2. In a shipping zone settings, disable / save any shipping method, then enable back / save. 
>    **You are done** and you can test it.

---

### Handling number of items instead of items cumulated quantity:

Replace:

```
$related_total_qty += $cart_item['quantity'];
```

by

```
$related_total_qty++;
```

Comment: This works perfectly but it seems to be causing conflict with the other rules I've set for two other shipping classes. I'm going to attempt to modify your code and replace class id with product id. There's only 7 products so I'll give it a bash. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: @WanderlustConsulting please make an edit at the end of your question and add the code that you were using for it, then notify me here once done… I will merge both to make that work.

Comment: I've just added a commented to the end of my initial question. It's a bit of a conundrum, so let me know if it's not clear enough.

Comment: I've figured out how to resolve this. Check out the edit for my proposed solution.